# how to config TYPO3 extension “news_ia” step by step

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have started using the TYPO3 extension "news_ia" and I would like to Generates Facebook Instant Articles :zap: RSS-feed with TYPO3 extension "news" (tx_news). 
How can i do this?

Comment: you did find the **[manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news_ia/)** and the **[news manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Rss/Index.html)** ?

Comment: yes. but for me the News Instant Articles manual not helpfull for me